# Filtrar lista de listas

Tags: lista-encadeada

Olá!
Tem como separar elementos de uma  lista de listas,sem que os mesmos se repitam?

Exemplo:
A partir da lista_pre,gerei as combinações necessárias usando o código do quadrado mágico,
modificando a condição de teste para validar as combinações se a soma delas fosse um múltiplo de 5.

```
Lista_pre = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

lista gerada a partir da lista_pre,usando código do quadrado mágico,para uma condição de saída--->sum(lista)%5 = 0,classe=2.
Ou seja, a soma dos elementos combinados da lista_pre sempre será um múltiplo de 5,nesse caso particular.
Produzio a lista_original,a qual preciso separar sem que existam elementos repetidos:

```
lista_original = [[6 , 9],[6 ,14],[6 , 19], [6 , 24], [7 , 8],[7, 13] ,
                    [7 ,18],[7 ,23],[8 , 12], [8 , 17], [8 ,22],[9, 11] ,
                    [9 ,16],[9 ,21],[10, 15], [10, 20], [11,14],[11,19] ,
                    [11,24],[12,13],[12, 18], [12, 23], [13,17],[13, 22],
                    [14,16],[14,21],[15, 20], [16, 19], [16,24],[17, 18],
                    [17,23],[18,22],[19, 21], [21, 24], [22,23]]
```

Resultado final esperado:

```
nova_lista1 = [[6,  9],[7,  8],[10,15],[12,13],[14,16],[17,18],[19,21], [22,23]]
nova_lista2 = [[6, 14],[7, 13],[8, 12],[9, 11],[10,20],[16,19],[17,23],[18,22],[21,24]
nova_lista3 = [[6, 19],[7, 18],[8, 17],[9, 16],[11,14],[15,20]]
nova_lista4 = [[6, 24],[7, 23],[8, 22],[9, 21],[11,19],[12,18],[13,17]]
nova_lista5 = [[11,24],[12,23],[13,22],[14,21]]
nova_lista6 = [[16,24]]
```

Em nenhuma das listas_novas existirão elementos repetidos:

Será usando em uma pesquisa que defino como Qm(n) ou Quadro Modulatório do inteiro n,onde, os coeficientes
calculados nas novas_listas,entram na composição do modelo de equilíbrio das relações entre divisores e não-divisores
naturais de um determinado número n.
Não existe regra de tamanho para nenhuma das listas:
Tamanho da lista_pre = 19----->variável por natureza em função do valor de n.
Tamanho da lista original = 35---->variável em função da classe combinatória usada.
Tamanho das novas_listas variam em função do modelo combinatório aplicado à lista pré, derivada do modelo 
de combinações possíveis para se chegar a um resultado proposto,abordado na programação do quadrado mágico.
Então o código terá que varrer as posições da lista_original,uma à uma,para gerar as outras novas_listas,quantas sejam,
sem que hajam elementos repetidos em cada nova_lista gerada.

Podem me ajudar,estou perdido!?

```
lista_saida = []
i = 0
lista=[[6,9],[6,14],[6,19],[6,24],[7,8],[7,13],[7,18],[7,23],[8,12],[8,17],[8,22],[9,11],[9,16],[9,21],[10,15],[10,20],[11,14],[11,19],[11,24],[12,13],[12,18],[12,23],[13,17],[13,22],[14,16],[14,21],[15,20],[16,19],[16,24],[17,18],[17,23],[18,22],[19,21],[21,24],[22,23]]
lista_saida.append(lista[0])  #Define  valor inicial de lista_saida
for x in range((1+i),len(lista)):#Atualiza início de busca até limite da lista
    for y in range(len(lista_saida)):#Procura elementos da lista_saida que estejam na lista,para não adotá-los
    if lista_saida[y][0]!=lista[x][0] and lista_saida[y][0]!=lista[x][1] and lista_saida[y][1]!=lista[x][0] and lista_saida[y][1]!=lista[x][1]:#Verifica índices
               lista_saida.append(lista[x])
        i+=1
```

Da estouro de pilha

Comment: Coloque um pouco do código, mostrando o que você já tentou fazer, e como está organizando a entrada de dados. é em Python, não? Marque a linguagem que você está usando nas tags também.

Comment: Aqui você só tem comentários - arrume sua pergunta como solicitado e poderá ter uma resposta com qualidade.

Comment: Infelizmente o método de lista append,não é acumulador então mesmo que consiga separar elementos não repetidos, à cada novo elemento selecionado a lista perde o elemento anteriormente selecionado, tentei usando discionário,deu  na mesma,então fiz o seguinte:vou separar o  1 elemento da lista de entrada eo que sobra dessa lista já pré-filtrada serão modelos combinatoriais possíveis para as associações .